# Problems converting byte array to collection of objects

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an input byte array into a collection of another data structure. The input byte array has a lot of bytes that correspond to a data structure that I call `Record`s which consist of 8 bytes for `data` (`long`) and 8 bytes for `key` (`double`) for each record. What I am trying to do is define a function that does this automatically because I will do this process very frequently. This is the function as I have it right now:

```
public Record[] bytesToRecord(byte[] byteArray) {
    Record[] arrayRecords = new Record[(byteArray.length/16)];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (byteArray.length); i+=16) {
        arrayRecords[i] = new Record(Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, i, i + 16));
    } 
    return arrayRecords;
}
```

So as you can see above, the function takes an array of bytes and loops through every 16 bytes to create a new `Record` object and appends it to the `arrayRecords`, which is the collection of `Record`s in a `Record` array. The problem I have is that I think something is going wrong so my function is not taking exactly 16 bytes per record, so when a `Record` object is created I get a `NullPointerException` in the `Record` class because it cannot properly slice the subarray of 16 bytes for a `Record` to get the `long` and `double` values for `data` and `key`. As follows there is the `Record` class constructor:

```
public class Record {
    private byte[] record;

    long idData = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 0,9)).getLong();

    double key = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 9,16)).getDouble();

    public Record(byte[] recordArray) {
        this.record = recordArray;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me to fix this function or suggest another method to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would provide some input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I identified four issues in your code that lead to failures in your code. I will go over each of them separately.

**Problem 1:** The problem giving you the `NullPointerException` has to do with your `Record` class. When a new class instance is created, the fields are initialized before the constructor is executed. This means in your case that `ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 0,9)).getLong();` runs before `this.record = recordArray;`. The problem then is that the first statement uses an array that was not initialized.

**Problem 2:** The index you use to specify the start of the `double` in the array is off by one. The long has 8 bytes 0 to 7 and the double the remaining 8 bytes from 8 to 15. The end index given to the method is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) to be 1 more than the actual end index.

So, to solve these two issues you have to change your `Record` to something like this:

```
public class Record {
    long idData;
    double key;

    public Record(byte[] recordArray) {
        this.idData = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 0,8)).getLong();
        this.key = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 8,16)).getDouble();
    }
}
```

**Problem 3:** In the function `bytesToRecord` you have a `for` loop starting at index zero until the index is smaller or equal than the length of the array. This has to be changed to strictly smaller as otherwise, the loop iterates one time too often.

**Problem 4:** You use the loop index for addressing entities in the `Record[]` and the `byte[]`, which have completely different lengths. The simplest solution is to iterate over the `Record[]` and calculate the index for the `byte[]`.

Something like this should solve these two issues:

```
public static Record[] bytesToRecord(byte[] byteArray) {
    Record[] arrayRecords = new Record[(byteArray.length/16)];

    for (int i = 0; i < (arrayRecords.length); i++) {
       arrayRecords[i] = new Record(Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, i*16, i * 16 + 16));
    }
        
    return arrayRecords;
}
```

**Edit:** An enhancement to your approach in my opinion would be to limit the `Record` class to only store the values and make all computations inside `bytesToRecord`. This way you don't have to copy parts of the array and save memory. The code should then look like this:

```
public class Record {
    long idData;
    double key;

    public Record(long idData, double key) {
        this.idData = idData;
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

```
public static Record[] bytesToRecord(byte[] byteArray) {
    Record[] arrayRecords = new Record[(byteArray.length / 16)];

    for (int i = 0; i < (arrayRecords.length); i++) {
        long id = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * 16, 8).getLong();
        double key = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * 16 + 8, 8).getDouble();

        arrayRecords[i] = new Record(id, key);
    }

   return arrayRecords;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I figure out some things along the way but your explanation helped me to improve my code